# Do python files need to be converted into an exe to run on users' computers?

Tags: python, executable

Will a python file run on a random user's computer just fine, or do I need to convert it into an .exe first and then send the .exe file to the user?

Thank you.

Comment: the other computer needs to have Python installed, otherwise it won't work as **.py**

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't understand your response. This is a straightforward, factual question. It's not open-ended nor asking for discussion. (It's probably a duplicate, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am asking how to make my code run properly.

Comment: It's not a question about writing the code. It's open-ended in that "a random user's computer" isn't well defined and requires interpretation - answers have to determine which factors are relevant. Further, simply finding out that conversion is necessary in a certain case, isn't going to be satisfactory - nobody would ask this without the immediate follow-on of "how do I do the conversion?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the random user has python installed on their computer then the file will run fine. If they don't have it installed, then you will need to convert it into an executable.

Answer (score 1):

For running the `.py` python script files, you would need python runtime installed on the end-user's machines. If you want to be able to package and send the python program as a self-contained binary (exe file), you can use something like https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to build the exe. This exe would package all your script files, their dependencies & the python runtime itself and can be run directly on the end-user's computers without installing anything extra.